# Detecting DownValue/OwnValue conflicts

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Occasionally I run into the following scenario -- one procedure uses a global function `f[x]` to do some computation, meanwhile another procedure does `f=5` which turns all subsequent calls `f[x]` into `5[x]`

I know about localizing variables, but I prefer to use global variables early in the development.

I can't think of a legitimate reason to mix OwnValues and DownValues. Is there a way to implement a warning message when situation like above happens?

In addition to tips below, default context can be found in OptionsInspector under Cell Options/Evaluation Options/CellContext

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Protect[f]` to avoid further assignments (of any kind) and `Unprotect[f]` to allow them again.

You could also do some simple hackery with up-values to prevent `Set[f, ...]` from actually putting own-values on `f` but still allowing the assignment of down-values without having to use `Protect`/`Unprotect`:

```
In[76]:= ClearAll[f]

In[77]:= f /: Set[f, x_] := x

In[78]:= f = 7

Out[78]= 7

In[79]:= f

Out[79]= f

In[80]:= f[x_] := x + 1

In[81]:= f[1]

Out[81]= 2
```

The above transparently blocks the use of `Set` on `f`. Issuing an actual message is straightforward too:

```
In[93]:= f::noov = "Blocked attempt to assign `1` as an OwnValue of f";

In[94]:= f /: Set[f, x_] := (Message[f::noov, x]; x)

In[95]:= f = 7

During evaluation of In[95]:= f::noov: Blocked attempt to assign 7 as
   an OwnValue of f

Out[95]= 7
```

Comment: What do you think about overriding Set/SetDelayed to print warning message if there's DownValue/OwnValue conflict?

Comment: Probably possible, but probably fragile. Have you considered using contexts instead (`Begin`/`End`) or setting cell/notebook-level contexts?

Comment: +1, I hadn't thought of using upvalues like that.  Clever.  Additionally, you make a good point about cell/notebook level contexts; I have found them to be one of the most useful improvements since v. 5.

Comment: I didn't know about notebook-level contexts, is that in Help pages somewhere?

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov, in Mathematica 7 follow this menu tree: Evaluation -> Notebook's Default Context (near the bottom) -> Unique to This Notebook or Each Cell Group.  This works as each Notebook/Cell Group have its own `Global`, in essence.  So, they do not interfere with each other.  The Cell Group context is nice when you have multiple paths of doing something and you wish to test them all.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer the original question about generating a warning message, but [Formal Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) are handy for use as global symbols.  They are automatically protected and therefore cannot be accidentally redefined.  You enter a formal symbol using the keystrokes `<ESC>$f</ESC>`, where `f` can be any letter.  The disadvantage is that it takes four keystrokes to enter the symbol instead of one.

Comment: +1 for the useful tidbit. Is it possible to programmatically generate (say, within a package) formal symbols out of double-struck or Greek letters? If not, I suppose the MakeBoxes examples in the Formal Symbols documentation would allow for substitution (of character and/or color). This could be a really useful design trick. :)

Comment: @telefunkenvf14 If you are referring to the distinctive visual appearance of the formal symbols (with the dots above and below), I do not know of a way to generate other such symbols.  As far as I can tell, the dotted letters are characters in a special font.  One could probably come close using `Underoverscript` and `Symbolize` but the results could be a hassle to enter from the keyboard.  The other characteristics of formal symbols, that they lack built-in definitions and are secured by `Protect`, are easy to arrange for any other symbol.